# Determine the HDMI controller from the command line

Tags: linux, hdmi

XBMC (or rather libcec) only supports CEC in a couple of HDMI controllers.

I would like a way to work out what HDMI / CEC controller is installed in a machine from the command line.

This is the machine I am looking at right now as an example, but I am looking for a general solution that would work for any machine from linux:

```
System Information
        Manufacturer: ASUSTeK Computer INC.
        Product Name: EB1012P
```

Perhaps a utility that can probe an HDMI controller to work out its capabilities?

Here is `lspci`:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx DMI Bridge (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation NM10 Family LPC Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [ION] (rev a2)
02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
05:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)
```

Comment: Does it show up in the output of lspci?

Comment: @fpmurphy `lspci` added to question

Comment: lshw might also be useful.

Answer (score 8):

### cec-client -l

1. Install(debian/ubuntu)

   ```
   apt-get install cec-utils libcec-dev
   ```
2. Run

   ```
   cec-client -l
   ```

   This will list all cec device on the system. If there is no CEC supporting device, `cec-client -l` will return `Found devices: NONE`, which is correct.

   Please keep in mind that most PC video card (Nvidia, AMD) do not support CEC(see PS2,PS3). The one known(have clear documentation/specification) GPU that support CEC is [VideoCore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Videocore), found in Raspberry Pi.

   PS1: `libcec-dev` is needed on Ubuntu 12.04 for `cec-client` to function correctly.

   PS2: Base on online forum post, Nvidia (GF, GT(ION), GTX) never claim to support CEC, nor deny. Nvidia website has no info about CEC. It basically don't say anything regarding this. I just take that as a "NO".

   PS3: For few [AMD PDF DOC](http://search.amd.com/us/_layouts/search/search.aspx?csquery=%20cec%20&collection=all-us) that mention CEC, it is clearly stated that it is not supported.

### xrandr --prop (This may or may help, my video card don't have cec to verify)

Following is a sample output

```
#xrandr --prop
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
    EDID:
        00ffffffffffff0010ac194050435341
        281101030e261e78eeee95a3544c9926
        0f5054a54b00714f8180010101010101
        010101010101302a009851002a403070
        1300782d1100001e000000ff00434333
        3838374136415343500a000000fc0044
        454c4c20313930374650560a000000fd
        00384c1e510e000a20202020202000d9
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Broadcast RGB:  Full
        supported: Full         Limited 16:2
    audio:  auto
        supported: off          auto         on          
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Broadcast RGB:  Full
        supported: Full         Limited 16:2
    audio:  auto
        supported: off          auto         on          
HDMI2 connected 1280x1024+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
    EDID:
        00ffffffffffff0010ac204045375241
        2811010380261e78eeee95a3544c9926
        0f5054a54b00714f8180010101010101
        010101010101302a009851002a403070
        1300782d1100001e000000ff00434333
        3838374136415237450a000000fc0044
        454c4c20313930374650560a000000fd
        00384c1e510e000a2020202020200090
    Broadcast RGB:  Full
        supported: Full         Limited 16:2
    audio:  auto
        supported: off          auto         on          
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Broadcast RGB:  Full
        supported: Full         Limited 16:2
    audio:  auto
        supported: off          auto         on
```

Comment: None of the previous commands worked for me. `cec-client -l` returned `Found devices: NONE`. `sudo xrandr --prop` didn't return any relevant info: `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080       0.0*`

Comment: Do you have cec function on that device? I filed to find any cec info on Nvidia GT218 from the web.

Comment: I don't know. That's why I'm looking for such a command. The device also has a nVidia ION 2 GT218.

Comment: Quoting from [wikipedia]: `CEC wiring is mandatory, although implementation of CEC in a product is optional.[57] It was defined in HDMI Specification 1.0 and updated in HDMI 1.2, HDMI 1.2a and HDMI 1.3a (which added timer and audio commands to the bus)`. So the pin and wire must be there, actual function may not. So it is possible that GT218 actually do not have cec support.

Comment: According to [this](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1981143) and [this](http://www.geekzone.co.nz/forums.asp?forumid=84&topicid=90683), it seems cec support in video card is rare, if any. That is why there are usb cec adaptor.

Comment: I knew this kind of device, but since OpenELEC natively supports HDMI-CEC on my Raspberry Pi, I was wondering if my HTPC could do the same. Anyway, thanks for your time and your attempt to awser the question.

Comment: Run cec-client on your raspberry Pi.

Comment: Raspberry Pi use [VideoCore GPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Videocore). That GPU support CEC. On machine with no CEC supporting devices, `cec-client -l` returning `Found devices: NONE` is the correct result.

Comment: xrandr was fine for me.